# AWS environment properties in docker compose

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to pass AWS 'Environment Properties' to my application running in docker container under beanstalk environment, deployed by github actions using docker compose.

I already have .env file defined and can access environment variables defined there. When I do not define variable in .env file, that variable can't be found from application level at all. The problem is that I can't access variables defined/updated in AWS console(environment > configuration > Environment properties). I've tried to declare variable in .env file and then update through AWS console but the value does not change. I have also tried to bypass env in docker-compose.yml as:

```
environment:
 - ENV_NAME=${ENV_NAME}
```

But it also didn't works.

Is it possible to set/update AWS Environment Property from AWS console level while docker is already running and expect that value of this env will be changed inside running container?